# Rails associations models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm new to rails and I have this problem

I have three models, provider model, product model and categorie model, all models are related.

If you enter a product, you can select provider and categorie for this product.

I can not delete a provider or a categorie because they relate to product

But I can remove a product without problems

As I can manage to eliminate a provider or gategorie without affecting product?

```
class Categorie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :provider
  belongs_to :categorie
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products
end
```

Thank!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dependent: destroy` on your has_many relationships so that when a provider with many products is deleted, the products are deleted as well:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem for deleting purpose. It will soft delete entities https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia